# How to setup a meson build system for a complicated project

Tags: meson-build

I have a project I am trying to port from makefiles to meson... and am just trying to figure out how to set it up so that everything builds correctly.

Where Foo A is made by combining `Platform/A/*` and `Foo/A/*` together and compiling everything... Bar A is made by combining `Platform/A/*` and `Bar/A/*` etc... And Foo/A, Foo/B, Foo/C are used together to make Foo.

Basically Platform contains device specific functionality... and Foo/Bar contain use specific functionality, that can change (via headers) some of the device specific values. such that platform/A cannot be compiled without Foo/A.

With a makefile this is doable, but ugly, and it is a pain to setup the dev environment... I am trying to figure out a more elegant way to do this.

```
rootdir
 - Common
 - Platform
   - A
     - inc/*
     - src/*
   - B
     - inc/*
     - src/*
 - Foo
   - A
     - inc
     - src
   - B
     - inc
     - src
# Seperate build, but has same build philosphy and relies on platform/*
 - Bar
   - A
     - inc/*
     - src/*
   - B
     - inc/*
     - src/*
```

Answer (score 1):

So in a perfect world, your `Platform` would not require external configuration headers to be provided in order for it to compile. If this were the case, then you could simply have this:

```
# meson.build
project(...)
subdir('Platform')
subdir('Foo')
subdir('Bar')

# Platform/meson.build
platform_lib = library('platform', platform..., include_directories: 'inc')
platform_dep = declare_dependency(link_with: platform_lib, include_directories: 'inc')

# Foo/meson.build
foo_lib = library('foo', foo..., include_directories: ['A/inc', 'B/inc'], dependencies: platform_dep)

# Bar/meson.build
bar_lib = library('bar', bar..., include_directories: ['A/inc', 'B/inc'], dependencies: platform_dep)
```

You could even omit the `subdir(...)` calls and inline all of the config in the top-level `meson.build`. A key benefit here is that **`Platform` is compiled exactly once, and re-used in the building of `Foo` and `Bar`**.

Assuming you can't rework `Platform`, then you can actually still use this template, with one small tweak:

```
# Platform/meson.build
# NOTE: No platform_lib anymore
platform_dep = declare_dependency(sources: platform..., include_directories: 'inc')
```

`dependency` objects can be thought of as a way to 'mix in' compilation and linkage information to a build target. So, when meson interprets `foo_lib = library(..., dependencies: platform_dep)`, it will add in all of the `platform...` sources to this target. The result is that your `Platform` gets compiled as part of the `Foo` build target.

However, this is also true of your `Bar` target. So, with this solution, you end up compiling `Platform` twice. If you have more than two targets, and `Platform` isn't particularly small, this can end up eating a lot of your build time. The first example I gave does not have this problem, as we will compile `Platform` once, and then simply link it with `Foo` and `Bar`.

There are some other solutions involving `subprojects` but I won't get into those unless this solution doesn't fit your needs.